# What is a "pre-pumped generator coroutine"?

Tags: python, generator, coroutine

I came across [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iKzOBWOHGFE) by James Powell in PyCon 2023 and he mentioned the concept of a "pre-pumped generator coroutine" (at 15:47).

This is the code that was showing as he mentioned it:

```py
@lambda x: lambda *a, **kw: [ci := c(*a, **kw), next(ci)][-1]
def c(*, mode):
    data  = yield
```

From what I researched "pumping" is related to (or the same as) "priming" a generator, which is the process of calling next() on a newly initialized generator to have it ready to receive data.

I was wondering, what is this concept and if someone could explain how is this function meant to be run?

Comment: This feels like a snippet of code that would shortly follow David Beazley saying "...and if you wanted to be extra diabolical"

Comment: The concept of priming is a lot simpler than the code shown :) -- that code is... well, I'd call it not very PEP-20 compliant, perhaps to the point of not being "practical" (within the meaning given in the second paragraph of https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: It would help if that one line of code didn't have two bugs. He seems sloppy.

Comment: @Kelly Anyone who writes codes like this and goes on to give a talk about it is suspicious by definition.

Comment: (Correction: he only had one bug, you added the other)

Answer (score 3):

DISCLAIMER: The lecturer presented this code just after writting in bold "Extreme Complexity", and followed the display of the snippet saying "do not use this code" loud and clear.

```
@lambda x: lambda *a, **kw: [ci := c(*a, **kw), next(ci)][-1]
def c(*, mode):
    data  = yield
```

So, first, as noted @kellybundy in the comments above, there are two incorrections in this code - let's get it right before proceeding:

```
@lambda c: lambda *a, **kw: [ci := c(*a, **kw), next(ci)][0]
def c(*, mode):
    data  = yield
```

So, let's go through parts: first, whatever follows the `@` and precedes a function or class is a decorator - and it needs to be a callable that will take the function as it sole argument.

1. Looking there we have a `@lambda c: ...` - therefore, it is a function that will take the decorated function as an argument, and return a new function. (could be any callable, but for simplicity, let's stick with the "function" word)
2. The body of a lambda function must be a single expression.  In this case, it is another lambda, going `lambda *a, **kw: ...` - this means that this inner lambda is the function that will replace the decorated function. The `*a, **kw:`  signature means it can take any number of positional and keyword arguments, and as we will see shortly, the only use for those is forwarding then into the original function (that is what the majority of decorators do, by the way)
3. The body of this inner lambda is a list with two expressions, followed by a an index  `[ci := c(*a, **kw), next(ci)][0]`.

   1. and that first element of the list is `ci := c(*a, **kw)` -

      1. here, the part `c(*a, **kw)` is what effectuate the actual call to the original, decorated function (the one starting with `def c: ...` in the snippet).
      2. The `ci :=`  part takes the return value of that call, and stores it in a temporary variable (`ci`). The same value is also used as the item at position 0 of the list (so, it is what will be returned by the inner lambda)
      3. Also note the `c` variable here is the parameter name of the outter lamba - `c` - which was incorrectly renamed to `x` when the snippet was transcribed from the video to this question. (`c` is correct): it refers to the decorated function. In the snippet it is also named `c`, but it could have any name.
   2. The second element of the inner lambda list, `next(ci)` will advance the generator stored in the `ci` variable, thus "pumping the generator". As expressions inside lists are executed in the order they appear, with the `,`  as an expression separator, this call takes place always after the generator was created, and stored both in the first (index 0) position of the list, and on the `ci` variable.
   3. And finally, `[0]` index will simply select select one item of the preceding  list `[ci: = ..., next...]` as the return value for the function (the inner lambda, which takes the place of the decorated function `def c():...`).

      1. This index is `[-1]` in the original code, and is the author's error - it should be `[0]` to indicate that the first element of that list is to be returned.

The final returned value, so, is whatever the original function returned, but after `next(...)` was called on it. If the decorated function is a generator function, as in this case, it is initialized up to the first `yield`, or "pumped" in the terminology used here.
The reason not to use it is plain obvious: although it takes a single line of code, it took ~30 lines of English text to explain what is taking place (and that, incidentally is the point of the lecturer on the video, *although he admits he actually **did** use this code at some point*)

And finally, this could be written in a few lines as a full `pump` decorator that could be actually usable:

```
from functools import wraps

def prepumped(func):
    @wraps func:
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
         gen = func(*args, **kwargs)
         next(gen)
         return gen
    return wrapper

@prepumped
def c(*, mode):
    data = yield
```

Comment: sorry - I've used `...`  through the write-up to indicate "here goes something we don't have to care", and just did the same in the final example function, when retyping it. But it is a syntax error as is, so  I am restoring the `*`, even though its signature does not matter for the example, all the same.